# Is "which is directly affecting our operational duties" correct in this sentence? Should it be "which are" instead?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, american-english

Is the following sentence correct:

> I would like to point upcoming events in Week 19, **which is** directly affecting our operational duties.

I think it should be "**which are**", and the verb affect usually I know it means negative, so could we interchange with "impact" or something else?

Comment: I would have thought *point **to** upcoming events*.

Comment: point out, also could be used.

Answer (score 1):

As Ronald Sole mentions, the verb "point" doesn't usually take a direct object (unless it is part of "point out", etc.). Therefore, this would be better:

> I would like to point to upcoming events in Week 19, which is directly affecting our operational duties.

Because the verb "is" is singular, its subject (the relative pronoun "which") is presumably singular, too. Therefore, "which" needs a singular referent. That appears to be "week 19", but that doesn't seem to make much sense. (It is possible, though.) The writer more likely means for "upcoming events" to be the referent. Because that is plural, "which" should be plural, so its verb should be plural:

> I would like to point to upcoming events in Week 19, which are directly affecting our operational duties.

"Affecting" is not inherently negative (it may easily be used with a positive connotation), but if you like, you could certainly replace it with a synonym, such as "impacting":

> I would like to point to upcoming events in Week 19, which are directly impacting our operational duties.

Note that [some people don't like to use "impact" as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/yes-impact-is-a-verb), although that is a minority opinion.

Comment: Good answer. But there is nothing wrong with "affecting" and "impacting" is not quite the same thing. Impact has a stronger sense than affect.

Comment: @WS2 Thanks. The difference between "affecting" and "impacting" seems pretty minor to me (perhaps that's just my sense), but I did edit to note that there was nothing necesarily negative about "affecting".

Comment: "Impacted" usually means that something damaging, or at least inconvenient has happened. But circumstances, while usually affected for the worse, can be affected for the better. "My previous need to self-isolate has been affected by the lower contagion among colleagues".

Comment: As you correctly pointed out in your edit - which I neglected to read until after I'd posted my comment. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Using commas on your questions will help us understand your question more easily and faster.

The sentence sounds good; "**which**" might be referring to either "**events**" or the whole action, *the upcoming events in Week 19*. Therefore, both can be considered to be correct. However, if you are referring to "**events**" on "**which**", then you should replace "**is**" for "**are**".

Certainly, you could replace "**affect**" for another verb that has a similar meaning, such as: *impact, reach*.